# Trouble bending an arm at the elbow once subdivided

Tags: modeling

I subdivided the arm at the elbow. Yet when I try to bend the arm at the elbow to move the elbow back, the shoulder moves instead. I am trying to position it like the arm drawn on the right.  Please help if you have any advice to get the arm to bend at the elbow. I am very very new to this.  Thank you for any help you can offer.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have all vertices of the arm selected, you need to select only the elbow vertex to bend your arm

Comment: It worked!  You are awesome!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to disable Limit selection to visible to see through the mesh, then select only the vertex of the elbow to bend the arm.

[image]